# How to use Like function of instabot module?

Tags: python, web-scraping, bots, instapy

I want to use instabot to like an image but there is no like happen I get false.

I tried to use unlike and worked

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()

bot = Bot(max_likes_per_day=999)
bot.login(username="my_user",password="pass")

get_id_of_link= bot.get_media_id_from_link("https://www.instagram.com/p/CFh766nAVfh/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link")
like = bot.like(media_id=get_id_of_link)

>>>[outPut] False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why are you using InstaBot for creating Instagram bot while InstaPy is the most popular and efficient Instagram library for automating Instagram. however, I read InstaBot documents and found no like method. instead, I reckon you should use `bot.like_all_exist_media()`.